# Don't see Failed Request Tracing in IIS Manager

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8, iis-8.5

In the "Actions" Pane of IIS Manager (InetMgr), under **Configure** there is supposed to be a link for *Failed Request Tracing*.

I don't see that... I just have "Limits..."?

Answer (score 44):

Install the **Tracing** component of the **Web Server** role through **Server Manager**.

It's in the Web Server (IIS) -> Health and Diagnostics area on all IIS versions from 7 up.

[image: Add Roles and Features Wizard on Windows Server 2016]
*(By the way: Whenever you add a component to IIS, you need to restart the IIS Manager GUI, to reload the UI modules. This doesn't apply to most other changes, because they happen "live" - it's just the user interface module list which is cached at startup.)*

**Failed Request Tracing** then shows up in the **Actions Pane** at the **Site** level, and needs to be **enabled there** before rules will fire.

[image: IIS Manager showing FREB Actions pane and Rules icon]

Then, you configure your Failed Request Tracing **rules** at any level within that site to capture what you want.

(FREB rocks!) (Failed REquest Buffering)

Comment: please don't forget restart IIS manager GUI, I killer hours figuring out why its that damn thing not logging a single byte.

Comment: +1 for the Configure screenshot - Azure was putting the logs on TempLocalStorage of course, not at the default location